# InverseFourierSinTransform in mathematika failed to give a result

Tags: integral-transforms

I have to use InverseFourierSinTransForm in Mathematika for the function u[ω,t] but infortunately it does not work.It gives back the same!
I tried it without the assumptions but it does not work again!
Any help please?How can I write InverseFourierSinTransform to find the result?
$$u(x,t)=\frac{2}{π}\int^{\infty}_{0}\hat{u}(\omega,t)sin(\omega x)d\omega$$

$$\hat{u}(\omega,t)= \sqrt{\frac{2}{π}}\frac{e^{-\omega^2 t}\omega}{\omega^2+a^2}$$

```
u[x_, t_] = InverseFourierSinTransform[v[ω, t], ω, x, Assumptions -> α > 0]
```

where $\hat{u} \to $  `v[ω,t]`

Comment: It would depend on the (missing) definition of `v`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau the ``` v[ω,t]``` is defined as the $\hat{u}$.I did n't give all the code because I think that it does not matter.Have you any idea what I have to add to run this?

Comment: It would require that definition for `v`.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the integral can be reduced to  finding

```
FourierTransform[Exp[- t omega^2]/(omega +- I a), omega, s]
```

because by partial fraction decomposition and diffentiating wrt to t

```
(1/(2*I*a*\[Omega]))*D[(E^(-t*\[Omega]^2)*(1/(\[Omega] + I*a)) - 1/(\[Omega] - I*a)), t]
```

Mathematica does not know, but searching the tables could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like:
$$\text{InverseFourierSinTransform}\left[\frac{\exp \left(-\omega ^2 t\right) \omega }{\omega ^2+a^2},\omega ,x\right]=\\\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sin (\omega  x) \left(\omega  \exp
   \left(-\omega ^2 t\right)\right)}{\omega ^2+a^2} \, d\omega =-\frac{e^{a^2 t} \pi  \left(e^{-a x} \text{erf}\left(a \sqrt{t}-\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)-e^{a x} \text{erf}\left(a
   \sqrt{t}+\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)+2 \sinh (a x)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}$$

```
  HoldForm[
  InverseFourierSinTransform[
  Exp[-\[Omega]^2*t]/(\[Omega]^2 + a^2)*\[Omega], \[Omega], x] == 
  Integrate[
  Sqrt[2/Pi]*
  Sin[\[Omega] x]*(\[Omega]*
  Exp[-\[Omega]^2*t]/(\[Omega]^2 + a^2)), {\[Omega], 0, 
  Infinity}] == -(1/(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]))*
  E^(a^2 t) \[Pi] (E^(-a x) Erf[a Sqrt[t] - x/(2 Sqrt[t])] - 
  E^(a x) Erf[a Sqrt[t] + x/(2 Sqrt[t])] + 2 Sinh[a x])]
```

Example **3.954.1** on page **535** from book: **"Table of
Integrals, Series, and Products
Eighth Edition-I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik"**